# CSS: Flexbox: responsive square div – width equal to [dynamic] height

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

On a `div` using `display: flex` I am facing a problem: the image/thumbnail should always be **square** based on parent-element height.

The parent element height is based on `.content` text.

[image]

Although the image is square by default, it's height is *way bigger* than the container and should be rescaled. If I use `height: 100%` it will determine 100% of the image height – not the parent element height.

Is it possible to achieve this with just CSS?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.element {
 display: flex;
 align-items: stretch;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -2px #000;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 /*
  * IMAGE
  */
 .image {
   background: #eee;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 20px;
   min-width: 20px;
   
   &:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     padding-top: 100%;
   }
   
   img {
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     max-width: unset;
     vertical-align: bottom;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
 }
 
 /*
  * CONTENT
  */
 .content {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 20px 0;
   margin-left: 10px;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="element">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple123/v4/19/46/66/194666a8-7e8d-2a7b-4390-c0688d603582/AppIcon-0-0-1x_U007emarketing-0-0-0-7-0-0-sRGB-0-0-0-GLES2_U002c0-512MB-85-220-0-0.png/230x0w.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    Wine corned beef strip steak tongue, pork chop chop chop.
  </div>

</div>
```

→ JsFiddle to play responsiveness: https://jsfiddle.net/hmaesta/w3eyz0b7/

I already tried the `padding-top: 100%` workaround, but it works if you have width – not otherwise.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: @Rob I just inserted the code here. I am sorry about this. The last time I asked a CSS question this feature did not exist...

Answer (score -1):

I might have 2solutions that you can try:
1 adding `width:100%; padding-top:100%;` instead of `height:100%;` to the image css
2 adding `display:block;` to the image css